# jquery can't get the id of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I try to get the id of li in listview by using following code

```
$("#detailr").append(" <li class=\"item box_btn\" id=\""+ item.appid +"\"><div class=\"list\" ><div class=\"list-left\"><img src=\"uploadb/"+ item.appicon +"\"><ul><li><b>"+ item.appname +"</b><span>Left"+ item.leftc +"</span></li><li><img src=\"img/32.png\">Done"+ item.appdone +"</li><li class=\"spe\">search\""+ item.appname +"\"</li></ul></div><div class=\"list-right\"><div class=\"yuan\">+"+ item.appprice +"</div></div></div></li>");});
```

and click events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#detailr').children('li').click(function () { // 
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
});
</script>
```

the html content

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="detailr">
</ul>
```

when I click the li, there no response, and I change `$('#detailr').children('li').click(function ()` to `$('#detailr li').click(function ()` , `$('#detailr').children('li').on("click", function ()`, also doesn't work, I don't understand why, please help me, many thanks.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#detailr').click('click', 'li', function () { // 
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});`

Comment: If `#detailr` contents are being created dynamically (after the DOM), then `.click` will not find the element. You will need `selector.on('click", "li", function() { // code });`

Comment: @Cory thank you, but it seems a bug with this, the alert will show twice, he first time has no value(shows undefined), the second time will show the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`.on()`** and **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** like so.

```
$('#detailr').on('click','li',function () { 
    alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but there's a bug, the alert will show twice, the first time has no value(shows undefined), the second time will show the id.

Comment: @spotcool Post your full jquery related code, easy for me to fix that and see the actual flow.

Comment: jquery-1.8.3.min.js & jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: I found why,  answer accepted, thanks a lot.